# Typeahead with Vue.js 2.0

Tags: vue.js, typeahead, bootstrap-typeahead, vuejs2

Total Vue noob here. Just wanted a typeahead component for Vue. Bootstrap has one, but I have no idea how to integrate the two!

And the only options I can find are either for Vue 1.x only or terribly documented (and the main effort to port Bootstrap components to Vue 2.x doesn't appear to include typeahead.)

Comment: have you checked vue-strap http://yuche.github.io/vue-strap/?

Comment: @flyingSmurfs yes. There's a branch moving it to Vue 2.0 (issue: https://github.com/yuche/vue-strap/issues/378), but the typeahead component currently in there only appears to work with Vue 1.0. (I do wish they'd make it clearer on the site! That was a waste of time finding out!!)

Comment: @NiketPathak this was asked 2 years ago. I'm not working on this any more! :)

Answer (score 4):

I've been a user of vue-strap, and it is not maintaining for a long time... (both vue 1 version and vue 2 fork)

check this out (created by myself): https://uiv.wxsm.space/typeahead/

(A simple but elegant typeahead implementation with Vue 2 & Bootstrap 3)

Install:

```
$ npm install uiv --save
```

Example usage:

```
<template>
  <section>
    <label for="input">States of America:</label>
    <input id="input" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Type to search...">
    <typeahead v-model="model" target="#input" :data="states" item-key="name"/>
  </section>
</template>
<script>
  import {Typeahead} from 'uiv'
  import states from '../../assets/data/states.json'

  export default {
    components: {Typeahead},
    data () {
      return {
        model: '',
        states: states.data
      }
    }
  }
</script>
<!-- typeahead-example.vue -->
```

Comment: Please provide a code example.

Comment: @Al0x example added.

Comment: @wxsm can you help with this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50158321/how-to-use-typeahead-in-my-vuejs-app ?

Comment: I am new to vuejs (1 day so far). I don't understand what to do with this code and your answer keeps coming up in all my searches. Should I create my own .vue file and paste this code inside? Should I drop this code directly in my html file?... Please help me to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this component:

https://github.com/pespantelis/vue-typeahead

Also, there is a great collection of vue components already:

https://vuecomponents.com

Comment: Vue-typeahead is what I was referring to when I said 'terribly documented' :) I think you meant to link to: https://vuecomponents.com/ - the www site is WEIRD. And, the only other similar component on vuecomponents is 'autocomplete' - which didn't /seem/ as good as Twitter's typeahead - but I might be wrong!

Comment: vue-strap typeahead

Comment: I'm currently working with this: https://github.com/trionfo1993/vue2-typeahead

Answer (score 0):

Try [wffranco's fork of vue-strap](https://github.com/wffranco/vue-strap). It aims to support Vue.js 2.x.x.
I tested the recent version from master (build 2.0.0-pre.11) and it works: https://jsfiddle.net/LukaszWiktor/kzadgqv9/

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="libs/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">

<div id="app">
    <typeahead v-model="value" v-bind:data="options"></typeahead>
</div>

<script src="libs/vue/vue.js"></script>
<script src="libs/vue-strap/vue-strap.js"></script>
<script>
    Vue.component("typeahead", VueStrap.typeahead);

    var app = new Vue({
      el: "#app",
      data: {
        value: null,
        options: ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
      }
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Great answer. How would you set it up so instead of just an array of strings, you were using a JSON object? E.g. `officeList = [{name: "abc", color: "red"}, {...snip..}]`